# How to select multiple frames from a sprite sheet in unity

Tags: unity, spritesheet

I have a sprite sheet and cannot figure out how to select multiple frames in unity 5.5 I am watching a tutorial and it doesn't say how to do it. Is there a button I have to press while clicking or is it having to change some settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the timing when you need or want to select multiple frames at once. But as I read it, you may just want to press control (CTRL) while clicking on your frames to select several of them at once.